# Subsonic : Object of type 'System.UInt64' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int64'

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I just hooked up Subsonic to MySql for the first time. Everything seems to be cool except a simple:

wp_1_post.All().ToList();

throws:

Object of type 'System.UInt64' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int64'.

It looks like the ID column in the wp_1_posts table is an unsigned bigint, just not sure what to do about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL.tt there is a check (GetSysType) which decides which type goes to which db type. At the moment we don't have a way to sense if something is unsigned (cause I don't know how) but what you would need to do is use "ulong" for unsigned bigint.

If you're up for helping us - it would rock. It would simply be writing some code that pulls whether a column is unsigned from the schema call in MySQL.tt. I don't know how to do it and I'm really slammed trying to find another job :)

Comment: awesome, thanks Rob.  Found a fix, unfortunately haven't had time to check out git yet, still kickin' it svn style. ;)  I'll email the changes to your gmail account if you wanna roll 'em in.  thanks!!

Comment: Can you please post changes here so that others can use?

Comment: @effkay guess not, and I need this fix really bad.