# I'm having a problem with unsigned data types iwith SubSonic 3 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, subsonic3, unsigned

I know others have "found" the issue an indeed I know where the issue is but it would be nice if the fix was posted as per the second link.

[Unsigned BigInt and bit issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802095/subsonic-mysql-unsigned-bigint-and-bit-issue)
[Subsonic : Object of type 'System.UInt64' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int64'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283615/subsonic-object-of-type-system-uint64-cannot-be-converted-to-type-system-int)

Basically I am having the same issues with Unsigned types in SUbSonic3. I know where to fix it I just don't have a clue where to start.

Please help someone who badly needs this fix in the templates :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Subsonic project (as well as the Subsonic Templates (separate propject) )is hosted on GitHub -

http://github.com/subsonic

Somone should already have a fix for this -

http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/issues/#issue/18

Comment: Thank you, seems to do the trick. Haven't tested it yet though.

Will now allow me full use of primary key. Not that I would ever expect my table(s) to get that many rows before doing a clean/restructure. 4,294,967,295 rows... in one table. Yikes.